# Android vertical layout assign equal weights (heights) to children

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have three horizontal layouts inside a vertical layout. I want these three horizontal child layouts to occupy the same space so I am adding weights (0.33) to each.

I am assigning the layout heights of the three child layout components to 0dp because the parent layout is vertical but the child layouts are not occupying equal height as expected.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/paper"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    tools:context=".TestActivity" >

         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scratchLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

             <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/topLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp" 
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/topArea1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:paddingRight="3dp"
                    android:text="Top Area 2"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/topArea2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:paddingRight="3dp"
                    android:text="Top Area 1"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/centerLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp" 
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/centerArea1"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                 android:text="Center Area 1" />

                 <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/centerArea2"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                 android:text="Center Area 2" />

            </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/BottomLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp" 
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/bottomArea1"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                 android:text="Bottom Area 1" />

                 <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/bottomArea2"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                 android:text="Bottom Area 2" />

            </LinearLayout>

         </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just a note for you, `layout_weight` on your vertical LinearLayout has no usages since `layout_weight` is not an attribute for RelativeLayout child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick notes: Nested weights leads to bad performance, avoid if possible. Don't mix `match_parent` and `fill_parent`. Just use `match_parent`.

Your main issue is that you have `layout_height="wrap_content"` for your outer `LinearLayout`, but then you have weights. You're specifying each child layout be 1/3 of the total, but then saying the total should be the sum of its children. Should each child layout be 1dp? 100dp? if you want each to be 1/3 of the whole screen, you should set `layout_height="match_parent"` for the outer `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kabuko, please change all fill_parent's to match_parent, however.

I recommend changing the height to 0dp as you mentioned but setting weight 1 for all of the LinearLayout's.

The weight value is a "factor" not a percentage.

Please refer to this [What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean) for a cleared example of how you might use layout_weight